# Where do I download : VBRun60sp6.exe (which installs Visual Basic 6.0 SP6 run-time files)?

Tags: windows, vb6

When I go to the MS web page describing the [latest VB Runtime Files list](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290887)  it directs me to [what looks like the right download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=7B9BA261-7A9C-43E7-9117-F673077FFB3C&displaylang=en) for VBRun60sp6.exe  but when I actually download it it's *VB6.0-KB290887-X86.exe* which is just the OleAut32.dll update for VB6.

I downloaded the VB6 IDE SP6 update but it installs directly to the Dev machine and I want to capture all of the files in one place. (If I do an /T extract from that update it doesn't have the .DLL files, etc. since it's an update).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download from:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7B9BA261-7A9C-43E7-9117-F673077FFB3C&displaylang=en

If you can't find, it check out this search:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Search/en-US?query=VBRun60sp6.exe

Comment: That, unfortunately leads down the same dead end, to the page i hyperlinked to. But it's the OleAut32.dll files not the VB SP6 update.

Comment: Did you try http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7B9BA261-7A9C-43E7-9117-F673077FFB3C&displaylang=en? It may say it's only the KB290887, but on my machine it extracted to vbrun60sp6, 1,005kb.

Comment: I downloaded the file and extracted it to an empty folder and all the run-time files listed in the manifest were present.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is ancient, but I found this via Google because I need to run some old, line-of-business application written in VB6 even today.

For those looking for the Visual Basic 6.0: Run-Time Redistribution Pack (SP6) (vbrun60sp6): none of the official Microsoft source has it anymore. So I ended up digging through some old backups of mine and I found a copy. I uploaded them here [vbrun60sp6 - Visual Basic 6.0: Run-Time Redistribution Pack (SP6)](https://turbolab.it/windows-10/risolvere-errore-componente-comctl32.ocx-dipendenze-non-correttamente-registrato-windows-10-download-pacchetto-dll-ocx-mancanti-2092)